# How to replace specific lines with regex?

Tags: regular-expression

Suppose I have a file that contains:

```
Time: 60 minutes
Seconds: 3600
Milliseconds: 36000
```

I would like to replace any word with `seconds`.

```
%s/seconds/time/g
```

What am looking for is after the replace,

```
Time: 60 minutes
Time: 3600
MilliTime: 36000
```

Basically, I would like to know how I can be more specific about only replacing lines that have Seconds in the string, and avoiding the others if there were more than just these 3 lines.

Comment: The example you give should work, is there something more specific you are having a problem with?

Comment: Your given command replaces with `time` (the other way around). Please add exact expected results, and a description of what exactly you're struggling with!

Comment: Say for example the file had:
`Time: 60 minutes
Seconds: 3600
Milliseconds: 36000`

What am looking for is after the replace,
`Time: 60 minutes
Time: 3600
MilliTime: 36000`

Basically, I would like to know how I can be more specific about only replacing lines that have Seconds in the string, and avoiding the others if there were more than just these 3 lines.

Comment: Read `:help :range`; it has all the details on how to be more specific than the global `:%` range.

Answer (score 8):

Swapping via regular expressions is performed by the ex command

```
:{range}s/pattern/string/{flags} {count}
```

If you wish to replace instances of a work on a specific line you can supply the exact line with the absolute location. To swap matches only on line 2:

```
:2s/Seconds/time
```

Or you can use a relative location using `-/+`. To swap only on a line two above the cursor:

```
:-2s/Seconds/time
```

Range can also be defined by using visual mode to select the area to perform the search. Visually select a region and press `:`

```
:'<,'>s/Second/time
```

Ranges can also be absolute or relative

```
:2,4s/Second/time
:-2,+2s/Second/time
```

The first does lines 2 through 4 and the second does 2 lines above the cursor to two lines below the cursor.

If you want to swap all cases you can supply the range and the flag `g` which finds all matches. Supply the `%` range for the entire document.

```
:%s/Seconds/time/g
```

Some commonly used flags are:

- `c`: Confirms each substitution (yes/no/abort/quit)
- `g`: Replace all occurrences in a line. Without this flag only the first instance on a line is swapped.
- `i`: Ignore the case of the pattern
- `I`: DO NOT ignore the case of the pattern

For further information check out the built in help `:h :substitute`.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from jecxjo's answer, there are also 2 other ways to replace only `seconds` and leave milliseconds` alone (without using ranges, which may be unwieldy for large files):

1. Anchor the pattern to the start of the line with `^`: `%s/^seconds/time/`; works in this specific case, but (obviously) won't work if you have an instance of `seconds` somewhere that *isn't* at the start of the line
2. More flexible is using a "word" match: `%s/\<seconds\>/time/`. The `\<` matches the "beginning of a word", and the `\>` matches the "end of a word"; so adding them both only matches if `seconds` is a word on it's own (and not part of a word); in this case, you could also use `:%s/\<seconds/time/`, because in `milliseconds`, `seconds` isn't at the start of the word.

Comment: Weirdly, from the comment: "What am looking for is after the replace, Time: 60 minutes Time: 3600 MilliTime: 36000".